# Create multiple sheets that uses same template using rubyxl

Tags: ruby, excel, rubyxl

I have an excel template which has only one sheet(Sheet1).Is it possible using rubyxl to generate multiple sheets that uses Sheet1 as template in my output file?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by following these steps:

## 1. parse xlsx/xlsm file

```
workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse(File.join(Rails.root, "public", "template.xlsm")
```

## 2. take worksheet template

```
template = workbook[0]
```

## 3. add a new worksheet to the workbook

```
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Example")
```

## 4. duplicate sheet_data

```
worksheet.sheet_data = template.sheet_data.dup
worksheet.sheet_data.rows = template.sheet_data.rows.map do |row|
  next unless row
  new_row = row.dup
  new_row.worksheet = worksheet
  new_row.cells = row.cells.map{ |cell| next unless cell; new_cell = cell.dup; new_cell.worksheet = worksheet; new_cell }
  new_row
end
```

Unfortunately `Marshal.dump` return error `no _dump_data is defined for class Nokogiri::XML::Namespace` for sheet_data's cells, so I had to write this dirty workaround.

## 5. copy everything else you need

```
worksheet.cols = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(template.cols))
worksheet.merged_cells = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(template.merged_cells))
```

for more attributes inspect `template.instance_variables`

You can also remove the template

```
workbook.worksheets.delete(template)
```

And return workbook with a new worksheet(s) by

```
send_data workbook.stream.string, filename: "example.xlsm", disposition: "attachment"
```

...in Your Rails controller

or just save it to file

```
workbook.write("path/to/desired/Excel/file.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template = RubyXL::Parser.parse 'path/to/template.xlsx'
sheet1 = template.worksheets[0]
sheet2 = template.worksheets[0]
#your code manipulating sheet1, sheet2 etc.
return RubyXL::Workbook.new [sheet1, sheet2]
```